# Obj-C - Remove specific custom annotation from MapView?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a mapView that displays many different custom annotations. That said, when a user taps a button on the map, I want ONLY annotations representing restaurants to disappear. Is there a way to hide a specific custom annotation? Here's my code so far.

**MapViewController.m**

```
       //DISPLAY RESTAURANTS ON MAP 
            
        -(void)viewDidLoad { 
        
             NSMutableDictionary *viewParams6 = [NSMutableDictionary new];
             [viewParams6 setValue:@"restaurants" forKey:@"view_name"];
             [DIOSView viewGet:viewParams6 success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 
                 self.neighbourhoodData = [responseObject mutableCopy];
               
                 int index = 0;
                 
                 
                 for (NSMutableDictionary *multiplelocationsFriend in self.neighbourhoodData) {
                     
                 
                     NSString *location = multiplelocationsFriend[@"address"];
                     NSString *userNames = multiplelocationsFriend[@"node_title"];
                      NSString *ampRemoved = [userNames stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"amp;" withString:@""];
                     NSString *removedAgain = [ampRemoved stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&#039;" withString:@"'"];
                     
                     
                     NSString *userBio = multiplelocationsFriend[@"body"];
                     self.x3 = multiplelocationsFriend[@"x3"];
              
                     NSString *latitude = multiplelocationsFriend[@"latitude"];
                     NSString *longitude = multiplelocationsFriend[@"longitude"];
                     
                     CLLocationCoordinate2D restLoc;
                     
                     restLoc.latitude = [latitude doubleValue];
                     restLoc.longitude = [longitude doubleValue];
                     
            
                                                MKCoordinateRegion region = self.mapView.region;
                                                
                                                region.span.longitudeDelta /= 350.0;
                                                region.span.latitudeDelta /= 350.0;
                                                
                                                
                                                RestAnnotation *point1 = [[RestAnnotation alloc] init];
                                                NSLog(@"What is Point 1 %@", point1);
                                              
                                                
                                                point1.coordinate = restLoc;
                                                point1.title = removedAgain;
                                                point1.subtitle = userBio;
                                               
                                                point1.index = index;  // Store index here.
                                               
                                                [self.mapView addAnnotation:point1];
                                       
                     index = index + 1;
               
                 }
            
                 
             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                 NSLog(@"Failure: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
             }];
        
        }
             
    
-(void)removeRestaurants {
    
    NSMutableArray *annotationsToRemove = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[self.mapView.annotations count]];
     for (int i = 0; i < [self.mapView.annotations count]; i++) {
         
    if ([[self.mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[RestAnnotation class]]) {
       [annotationsToRemove addObject:[self.mapView.annotations objectAtIndex:i]];
      }
     }

     [self.mapView removeAnnotations:annotationsToRemove];
    NSLog(@"ANNOTATIONS TO REMOVE %@", annotationsToRemove);
}
```

Comment: `removeRestaurants:` is kinda funny code, quarantine? kidding. What about `[self.mapView removeAnnotation:self.mapView.annotations[index]];` your focus is already in the right direction.. try to figure out how to reach the index you want..

Comment: Lol... @OlSen aren't you witty. Haha. And re: reaching the index I want, I'm not sure how to go about this? My 'removeAnnotations' isn't even executed when checking the RestAnnotation class type? :/

Comment: @OlSen MKAnnotationView :)

Comment: ok when sender is `__kindof MKAnnotationView *obj` and you are sure it was `RestAnnotation` then you can cast to `RestAnnotation *point1 = (RestAnnotation*)sender;` but you want to filter all RestAnnotation from self.mapView.annotations

Comment: I'm super confused/lost lol - are you able to put this in answer format? @OlSen

Comment: confused is not a superclass. :) you want to throw out all RestAnnotation that are restaurants?

Comment: @OlSen LOL yes! See edit above. This seems to give me the range of annotations I want to remove...but 'removeAnnotation' does nothing.

Comment: I've done it! Lol. See edit above. Works like a charm. @OlSen

Answer (score 0):

lets compare and spot the differences to your edit.

```
-(void)removeRestaurants:(id)sender {
#pragma unused(sender)

    NSMutableArray *kickMeOut = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSUInteger index = 0; index < self.mapView.annotations.count; index++) {
        if ([self.mapView.annotations[index] isMemberOfClass:[RestAnnotation class]]) {
            id<MKAnnotation> candidate = self.mapView.annotations[index];
            [kickMeOut addObject:candidate];
        }
    }
    
    for (id<MKAnnotation> obj in kickMeOut) {
        [self.mapView removeAnnotation:obj];
    }
}
```

see: i used `isMemberOfClass:` to make sure it kicks the correct members out.

you could also

```
for (id<MKAnnotation> candidate in self.mapView.annotations) {
    if ([candidate isMemberOfClass:[RestAnnotation class]]) {
        [kickMeOut addObject:candidate];
    }
}
[self.mapView removeAnnotations:kickMeOut];
```

which is shorter.. (untested)